# Can't find Numpy in Windows 8

Tags: python, numpy, windows-8

I tried to run a code that imports Numpy, but it shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MarcosPaulo\Dropbox\Marcos\Desacelerador Zeeman\Simulação da desaceleração atômica\Programa\Dy_deceleration.py", line 4, in <module>
import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I ensure you that I have Python 2.7 and Numpy 1.1 installed on my laptop.

Comment: Is numpy in \Python27\Lib\site-packages?

Comment: I don't why, but I can't write "Hey, everybody!" on the top... Every time I try to do it the mensage only shows "everybody!".... Hahaha

Comment: No, it's not... Do I must paste the Numpy folder in this directory?

Comment: Well, I tried to do it and then it shown

   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MarcosPaulo\Dropbox\Marcos\Desacelerador Zeeman\Simulação da desaceleração atômica\Programa\Dy_deceleration.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.

Comment: Did you do the right installation command?

Comment: I installed miniconda on my laptop and then I wrote "conda install numpy" in cmd. I'm sure Numpy is installed. Both Python and Numpy are up to date.

Comment: Try closing, waiting, and reopening the interpreter.

Comment: Does xgoogle work as numpy? Okay, I will

Comment: xgoogle is in the same site-packages folder on my computer. I'll try numpy (downloading...).

Comment: I see. I'm a beginner in Python coding... I tried what you said, but it shown the same mensage

Comment: I received this [message](https://www.scribd.com/doc/292695757/Error-Message). I will start a new question for mine, though. I will keep researching.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much, Clayton.

Comment: Was installation smooth (no errors)?

Comment: Yes place the numpy directory in site-packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this download location](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). It worked for me. Use **cmd** to do `pip install numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl` (or conda) for whatever one you downloaded.

**EDIT:** Restart your python shell, and **import sys**. Also make sure your installment location is in your `sys.path` by printing it out to the screen. It should include `'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'`.

After that, do a loop of python **command line** (shell) **outside the `numpy` directory** and with `import numpy;numpy.test()` a couple of times until you get no fails. It might take a while to test.

Comment: When I tried to install in **cmd**, it shown `numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. Any ideia?

Comment: Try `pip` to install it.

Comment: @MarcosPauloMiotti are you sure you don't need the 64bits version like *numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl* on the same website? Then try `pip install numpy-1.10.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Sorry for holding you up. Now I installed correctly Numpy. It shown again `Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.` when I tried to do what you said. I tried to remove the numpy directory with `sys.path.remove(\...)` and to restart the Python. It still shows the same error message and when I try to use `sys.path` commands, it prints `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`...

Comment: Just make sure your `site-packages` is in the `sys.path` and your **numpy* folder is in the `site-packages` as explained the new answer.